# How to move objects along with mouse cursor in AS 3.0 with continuances loops?

Tags: animation, web, simulation, game-physics

First checkout this link:

https://www.g-star.com/en_nl/raw

It's a simple canvas that has some characters and moving along with mouse cursor on x and y axis. When you click on particular character, it comes in focus and give a brief, like charterer cloths in GTA.
But I don't understand how they made continuous loop that doesn't stop.
Can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read here: https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask a question properly. We don't accept code requests.

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't understand how they made continuous loop that doesn't
>   stop.

you could use a while loop:

In most computer programming languages, a while loop is a control flow statement that allows code to be executed repeatedly based on a given Boolean condition.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop

In which language are you programming?